# Can I specify supportedRuntime (or any other config parameter) without a .config file in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, configuration, windows-8

I have a WinForms app that should be really easy to deploy with just and .exe file. It uses framework 2.0, and so it does not work on Windows 8 by default. If I include a .config file with the following parameters, it works fine on W8:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

However, now I have to deploy two files and this is not acceptable. Is there some thing I can do to "embed" those parameters into the exe itself?

I have tried using WinZip self extractor, but it's not an option either, because I cannot customize its interface.

Comment: I will post an answer myself. IExpress, included wiht Windows, seems like a good solution to he problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

.NET executable contains small piece of native code, which is intended to load appropriate CLR version into a process.

Loader calls *shim* (MSCOREE.DLL, .NET executable has native dependency from this DLL) to load CLR ([CLRCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537633) in v4).
Content of [`<startup>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h) configuration element is processed by the shim.

This means, you can't process `<startup>` element in managed code, because there's no CLR (and any managed code) at this moment. The only way is to write your own CLR host. I think, it is much easier to ship your application with config file, or build a version for .NET 4/4.5.

Comment: You're certainly right that information controlling .NET version has to be processed in native code without the help of managed anything.  But then you make a leap from there to the config file, as if native code is only allowed to read config files and not (for example) the PE header or manifest resource stored in the .exe  Probably you're right and the config file is needed, but if so, that is because the shim is coded to only read the config file, and not because of any technical difficulty in making a native shim that checks the .exe file.

Comment: It would be great to have a shim that loads config from embedded resource inside exe. I'm wondering if there are any alternative CLR shims with more configuration options.